# Jenkins: Agent went offline during the build

Tags: jenkins

Currently I am running tests with Jenkins on multiple virtual machines (VM), with both Linux( openSuse 64-bit) and Windows 7 (x64).
My VMs are located on a server running on Linux.
My version of Jenkins is 2.2
Strangely, sometimes my agent goes offline without any reason. And by doing so, my build fails.

From what I previously read on the internet, some people caim to be a problem with the [Timestamper](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper) plugin. Well, I do not have it installed.

What is even more strange, on Windows I get this error more often than on Linux. So far I've disabled 'Hibernate' and 'Sleep' in Windows, but that was not the cure to my problem.And in most of the cases it goes offline after ~1:30 hours of running.

**Configuration of my slave**

1. *Virtual machine Type*      - headless
2. *Virtual machine stop mode* - powerdown
3. *Secondary launch method*   - Launch agent via Java Web Start
4. *Availability*              - Keep this agent online as much as possible

Also, in Windows I've created a .bat file in Startup folder that connects to my agent every time Windows boots up.

Any idea why it is happening this or how to solve it?

```
Agent went offline during the build
ERROR: Connection was broken: java.io.EOFException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$3.run(NioChannelHub.java:614)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT (25.08.2016): 4/50 build succeded, but all the rest failed.

EDIT : All what I got so far  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-36944

Comment: Do you have slave logs.....

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this problem recently. I am running Redhat linux 6. Previously I was launching slaves through Java webstart and then I changed to use ssh connection. I changed from java web start because when I updated that java it seems javaw was failing for some  reason. I needed to get off that old java. That's why I changed over. I am still seeing these errors where a build will fail because the agent goes offline for some reason. [image: JenkinsBuildError]I'm gonna try to update the VM and restart and see what happens. BTW I also don't have Timestamper plugin. Sorry I don't have more of an answer. I thought I would add my experiences and info to see if that helps.

Comment: If it's not really an answer, consider maybe putting it in a comment instead? Comments are the perfect place for drilling down to the problem and helping define the issue. Answers should be decisive solutions.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you for the guidance

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: I am still launching slaves using ssh connection and it is working very reliably for me after my initial issues. The java web start caused problems when trying to upgrade the java and I'm glad it did because that's what made me switch to ssh.